# Converting UTF-8 to ASCII

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, mb-convert-encoding

When I convert a sample string like this:

```
$str = "Ø§ÙˆÙ‚Ø§Øª-Ø´Ø±Ø¹ÛŒ-Ø¬Ù…Ø¹Ù‡-8-Ù…Ø±Ø¯Ø§Ø¯-Ù…Ø§Ù‡-Ø¨Ù‡-Ø§ÙÙ‚-Ø§Ø±Ø¯Ø¨ÛŒÙ„"
    echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "ASCII");
```

from UTF-8 to ASCII the result should be this:

> %D8%A8%D8%B2%D8%B1%DA%AF-%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%B2%D8%B4%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AE-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%BE%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B1

But it's this :

> ?????????????????????-????????????????-??????????????????-8-?????????????????????-??????????????-?????????-?????????????-?????????????????????????

I'm really get confused Anyone knows the problem?

UPDATE : I also tryed iconv:

```
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII", $str), PHP_EOL;
```

But it says :

> Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Comment: did you tell the output environment it should be in ascii? if you do utf->ascii and then spit that ascii out into a utf environment, it will get trashed.

Comment: try iconv function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: I would assume that characters that aren't available in the destination encoding would be replaced by a placeholder character (`?` in this case)

Comment: Why do you think the output should be what you've written above?

Answer (score 4):

%D8 is not ascii encoding. Ascii has 127 (or 255 if you're using extended) characters (see http://www.asciitable.com/)

As such, special characters like Ø have no equivalent. `mb_convert_encoding` handles this by replacing them with a ?, whereas `iconv` throws an error.

The output you're after looks more like url encoding.
Try this:

`echo urlencode("Ø§ÙˆÙ‚Ø§Øª-Ø´Ø±Ø¹ÛŒ-Ø¬Ù…Ø¹Ù‡-8-Ù…Ø±Ø¯Ø§Ø¯-Ù…Ø§Ù‡-Ø¨Ù‡-Ø§ÙÙ‚-Ø§Ø±Ø¯Ø¨ÛŒÙ„");`

Comment: if you check the encoding type of that by mb_detect_encoding() you see its ASCII.

Comment: The encoding type of the string "%D8" will be ascii, yes, because % D and 8 _on their own_ are ascii characters. But that is not the same thing as %D8 in url encoding. D8 is 216 in hex, which is unicode character for Ø. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d8/index.htm

Comment: Interpretation of the string is largely down to whatever is reading it. If you say "%D8" is ascii, you will get % D and 8 as separate characters. If, however, you say it's url encoding, you will get Ø

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the problem with this case is that the input string is wrong and the conversion between ASCII and UTF-8 is unnecessary.

Lets start with this

```
$out = '%D8%A8%D8%B2%D8%B1%DA%AF-%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%B2%D8%B4%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AE-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%BE%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B1';
```

When we try to get encoding of this string with

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($out);
```

then we can see that is ASCII ofcourse. But as we can see this string evidently looks like the output of the `urlencode` function. Lets try to use a `urldecode` function to check what is the encoding of that value

```
$decoded = urldecode($out);
echo mb_detect_encoding($decoded);
```

On the output we can see that `$decoded` is an UTF-8 so trying to run this code from the question

```
$str = "Ø§ÙˆÙ‚Ø§Øª-Ø´Ø±Ø¹ÛŒ-Ø¬Ù…Ø¹Ù‡-8-Ù…Ø±Ø¯Ø§Ø¯-Ù…Ø§Ù‡-Ø¨Ù‡-Ø§ÙÙ‚-Ø§Ø±Ø¯Ø¨ÛŒÙ„"
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "ASCII");
```

have no sense because there can't be ASCII encoding.

I was also be curious what is encoding of the `$str` from the question so I prepared something like this to find if I can get the `$str` value from `$decoded` value

```
foreach (mb_list_encodings() as $chr) {
    $test = mb_convert_encoding($decoded, $chr, 'UTF-8');
}
```

I was surprised that I didn't find any encoding that can give me something similiar to `$str` value. I've try to do more and check conversion like in this code

```
foreach (mb_list_encodings() as $chr) {
    foreach (mb_list_encodings() as $chr2) {
        $test = mb_convert_encoding($decoded, $chr, $chr2);
    }
}
```

and I've finally found some values looks similiar but not equal. I've do the same with the oryginal `$str` but also without success (I didn't get the request output from the question).

```
foreach (mb_list_encodings() as $chr) {
    foreach (mb_list_encodings() as $chr2) {
        //try with and without urlencode
        $test = urlencode(mb_convert_encoding($str, $chr, $chr2));
    }
}
```

Ofcourse when we do this

```
$newOutput = urlencode($decoded);
```

then we get the `$out` value.

The conclusion is that the conversion between ASCII and UTF-8 is obviously unnecessary in this case and the input string may be wrong (mayby because of some unnecessary confersion from UTF-8 to something I can't recognize).